# Getting the mimeType from a MediaRecorder that wasn't initialized with a mimeType

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I'm using the MediaRecorder API to record some media on a page.  In my MediaRecorder initialization, I'm not specifying content type as I do not require anything in particular.  The browser can choose what it wants.

```
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

However, when it comes time to save that recording, I need to know the mimeType for the blob, and so I can determine a reasonable file name extension.

The [MediaRecorder.mimeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/mimeType) proprety is what I want, but it is an empty string.  It doesn't set `mimeType` to the default for MediaRecorder, so I have seemingly no way to know what the default `mimeType` is.

```
  mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
    var mediaFileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob(chunks, {type: /* TODO: mime type here */})
    );

    $('<a>').attr({
      href: mediaFileUrl,
      download: 'Recording.?????' // TODO: Use mime type to figure out file name extension
    })[0].click();

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(mediaFileUrl);
    chunks = [];
  }
```

Comment: @guest271314 An array containing segments of encoded media.

Comment: Encoded in which format? Is `chunks` an `ArrayBuffer`? Could you provide user with option to choose a `MIME` type to record in before recording begins? Then set `Blob` `type` to selected `MIME`, instead of permitting browser to select a `MIME` type; which appears to be setting an empty string? You could also utilize `isTypeSupported` to determine if browser can play a specific media type.

Comment: See [isTypeSupported](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/MediaRecorder.html#dom-mediarecorder-istypesupported)

Comment: See https://addpipe.com/blog/mediarecorder-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to get the information you need out of the box.

The current W3C specification states that if the mimetype is not specified (by you):

> the UA will use a platform-specific default format.

That's what happening in your case, you're not specifying any mimetype and the UA, the browser is choosing the best suited type for you and there is no specification regarding a way to get the chosen format back.

Right now, the only method that can get you close to that is to use `isTypeSupported` that provides some media support detection, unfortunately with the amount of mimetypes, browsers, platforms, rates, etc., it's not well suited to write a function which will return the mimetype chosen with the number of combinations available: `video/webm; codecs="vp"`, `video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d4015"`, etc.

The original idea might have been to hide all these details from the user but indeed, your specific case where the user need to know the mimetype in order for example to save the generated file is something that comes up very often.

[An issue](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/59) is currently opened with a proposition to provide a way to get all supported media types ordered by weak preferences, which means that the first media type returned would be the default one chosen by the UA if not provided.

The issue was created in May but no actual follow-up at the moment.

Comment: Update: Chrome bug https://crbug.com/615940 traced a similar issue and was Fixed, so the produced encoded Blobs should have a `mimeType` correctly specified.

Answer (score -1):

For audio, the default seems to be `audio/ogg`, and for video `video/ogg`. Tested in both Chrome and Firefox with VLC.

**Demo**: https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/9/result

Comment: This is not guaranteed, and is subject to change in future browser versions.  Also, I usually get webm, not ogg.

Comment: While that is true, this is the only way to get the correct mime now. The only other option is to do client-side content sniffing, which isnt easy

Comment: Can you conclusively show that it isn't possible with existing APIs?  (Short of type sniffing.)  I'd happily award the bounty to someone who could definitively prove it isn't possible.

Comment: `https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/9/result Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Works for me, maybe problem on your end?

Comment: @jDawg Was able to load page