# Capturing audio data (using javascript) and uploading on a server as MP3

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

Following a number of resources on the internet, I am trying to build a simple web page, where I can go to record something (my voice), then make a mp3 file out of the recording and finally upload that file to a server.

At this point I can do the recording and also play back, but I haven't gone as far as uploading, it seems like I cannot even make an mp3 file locally.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or in the wrong order?

Below is all the code I have at this point.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>Audio record and playback</h2>
    <p>
        <button id=startRecord><h3>Start</h3></button>
        <button id=stopRecord disabled><h3>Stop</h3></button>
        <audio id="player" controls></audio>
        <a id=audioDownload></a>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
  var player = document.getElementById('player');

  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            player.controls=true;
            player.autoplay=true;
            // audioDownload.href = player.src;
            // audioDownload.download = 'sound.data';
            // audioDownload.innerHTML = 'Download';
            mp3Build();
        }
    }

    player.src = stream;
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true/*, video: false */})
      .then(handleSuccess);

startRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = true;
  stopRecord.disabled=false;
  audioChunks = [];
  rec.start();
}

stopRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = false;
  stopRecord.disabled=true;
  rec.stop();
}


var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

function mp3Build() {
try {
    var process = new ffmpeg('sound.data');
    process.then(function (audio) {
        // Callback mode.
        audio.fnExtractSoundToMP3('sound.mp3', function (error, file) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('Audio file: ' + file);
        audioDownload.href = player.src;
        audioDownload.download = 'sound.mp3';
        audioDownload.innerHTML = 'Download';
      } else {
        console.log('Error-fnExtractSoundToMP3: ' + error);
      }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to investigate and see what is happening using the Debugger inside the Web Console; on the line:

```
var process = new ffmpeg('sound.data');
```

I get this message:

```
Paused on exception
TypeError ffmpeg is not a contructor.
```

And on the line:

```
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
```

I get this message:

```
Paused on exception
ReferenceError require is not defined.
```

Beside when I watch the expression ffmpeg, I can see:

```
ffmpeg: undefined
```

After some further investigations, and using browserify I use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>Audio record and playback</h2>
    <p>
        <button id=startRecord><h3>Start</h3></button>
        <button id=stopRecord disabled><h3>Stop</h3></button>
        <audio id="player" controls></audio>
        <a id=audioDownload></a>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var player = document.getElementById('player');

  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            //player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //player.srcObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            //player.srcObject = blob;
            player.srcObject = stream;
            player.controls=true;
            player.autoplay=true;
            // audioDownload.href = player.src;
            // audioDownload.download = 'sound.data';
            // audioDownload.innerHTML = 'Download';
            mp3Build();
        }
    }

    //player.src = stream;
    player.srcObject = stream;
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true/*, video: false */})
      .then(handleSuccess);

startRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = true;
  stopRecord.disabled=false;
  audioChunks = [];
  rec.start();
}

stopRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = false;
  stopRecord.disabled=true;
  rec.stop();
}


var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

function mp3Build() {
try {
    var process = new ffmpeg('sound.data');
    process.then(function (audio) {
        // Callback mode.
        audio.fnExtractSoundToMP3('sound.mp3', function (error, file) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('Audio file: ' + file);
        //audioDownload.href = player.src;
        audioDownload.href = player.srcObject;
        audioDownload.download = 'sound.mp3';
        audioDownload.innerHTML = 'Download';
      } else {
        console.log('Error-fnExtractSoundToMP3: ' + error);
      }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
}
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That solved the problem of:

```
the expression ffmpeg being: undefined
```

But the play back is no longer working. I may not be doing the right thing with *player.srcObject* and maybe some other things too.

When I use this line:

```
player.srcObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I get this message:

```
Paused on exception
TypeError: Value being assigned to HTMLMediaElement.srcObject is not an object.
```

And when I use this line:

```
player.srcObject = blob;
```

I get this message:

```
Paused on exception
TypeError: Value being assigned to HTMLMediaElement.srcObject does not implement interface MediaStream.
```

Finally, if I use this:

```
player.srcObject = stream;
```

I do not get any error message but the voice recording still does not work.

Comment: check console if there is "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" then take a look here "https://github.com/substack/node-browserify"  as for the type in new Blob it's better to use the one supported by the browser check this "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported" also there is no need for  if (window.URL) {
      player.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
      player.src = stream;   /*  you should do player.srcObject = stream;   */
    }

Comment: The first link that you mention doesn't seem to work, and the second is only half working.
Beside, I have tried to make use of what I can get from your comment and I edited my post, adding some more information at the end. But I feel like I still have some work to do before everything works.

Comment: I seriously don't understand what happened this is the first link 
 https://github.com/browserify/browserify  and this is the second 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported

Comment: Thanks! The links are now working.

Comment: Why does it have to be an MP3?  You'll get much better audio quality and browser support if you allow for Opus.

Comment: MP3 is just a common format and usually does not take too much space. I am thinking of later uploading the recordings to a server for people to download. But indeed MP3 is not an absolute necessity. I am opened to better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`require` doesn't work in the browers.

you should use "browserify"  this is its github page https://github.com/browserify/browserify

also it's better (if it is not necessary) to use the browser MediaRecorder supported audio type in new Blob check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported%22

last of all there is no need for `player.src = stream;` in your code (I am speaking of second one) plus it will give you an error check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#Basic_example

This is a little edite

```
    var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            player.controls=true;
            player.autoplay=true;
            audioDownload.href = player.src;
            audioDownload.download = 'sound.data';
            audioDownload.innerHTML = 'Download';
            mp3Build();
        }
    }

    //No need to put anything here
  };
```

Comment: Note that `isTypeSupported` is completely useless for determining whatever format was actually recorded with MediaRecorder.  In fact, even if you use `isTypeSupported` and initialize the MediaRecorder with one of those types, there is no guarantee that's what you actually get out of it.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/38337626/362536

Comment: @evgeni fotia Thank you for this enlightment. I think I have now solved the "require" issue, thanks to your tip.
But the playback is no longer working; in other words I cannot record my voice anymore. I have updated the post (adding at the end) to reflect the current situation.

Comment: That may not be the right way to do but if instead of using player.srcObject I go back using player.src as I did before I can make the playback feature work again.

Comment: sorry thats not what I mean. I edited my answer a little

Comment: OK, thanks; I understand. My problem now is that my mp3Build() does not seem to do anything good. I want to make a (mp3) file out of the recorded voice, in order to do something with it; but this does not yet work.