# Correct mime type to record and save audio with MediaRecorder

Tags: html, mediarecorder

I would like to record and save to file a short audio recording in a compact form as possible.

I have this mostly working except for the file type.  When I use this to try to save as MP3, I get an error saying the file type is not supported.

```
const options = { mimeType: "audio/mpeg" };
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

What would be the correct mimeType to use to save it to a playable file?

Or do I need to convert it to MP3 on the server after it is uploaded?

Comment: does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337626/getting-the-mimetype-from-a-mediarecorder-that-wasnt-initialized-with-a-mimetyp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have learned:

1. There is a list of [supported Mime Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739837/all-mime-types-supported-by-mediarecorder-in-firefox-and-chrome).  If your type is not in the list, an exception like the above will be thrown.

2. The default mime type if no options are specified is "webM", meaning if you save this to a file with this extension on Windows, Windows Media Player will play it back successfully.
3. MP3 is a proprietary format and will never be supported. However, there are non-proprietary formats like `webm` that will substitute just fine.